# enh-ruby-mode and Ruby 3.1 syntax

Tags: ruby, emacs

From what I see, enh-ruby-mode doesn't seem to support the latest Ruby syntax updates of 3.1, ["value omission in Hash literals"](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/commit/c60dbcd1c55cd77a24c41d5e1a9555622be8b2b8) to be exact.

Is there a way to solve it?

[image]

If that's important, I'm using rbenv.

enh-ruby-program is "~/.rbenv/shims/ruby".

Ruby version is 3.1.2

`ruby -c path/to/file` outputs `Syntax OK` for the same file.

`enh-ruby-mode` plugin version is 20210120.201

As a workaround, I had to set `enh-ruby-check-syntax` for that 3.1 Ruby project.

Comment: I see the issue you raised with `enhanced-ruby-mode` related to this issue is closed. Can you self answer or close this question? https://github.com/zenspider/enhanced-ruby-mode/issues/191